# pyqt4 creating dynamic check box buttons

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I was trying to create a `pyqt` gui which will display the folder name inside a particular folder, say display all folders inside "XYZ" folder as checkbox items .

How to do that in pyqt?

Answer (score 0):

i am using below code to list the folders, How do i check which check box is selected ????

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.checks = []
        fldrs=[name for name in os.listdir(".") if (os.path.isdir(name)) ]
        for list in fldrs:
            c = QCheckBox("%s" % list)
            layout.addWidget(c)
            self.checks.append(c)

        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```